# Timefold: Employee scheduling with variable number of employees per shift?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold, domain-modelling

I am trying to create a domain model for my situation, using Timefold's Employee Scheduling example as a starting point.
The main difference in our business domain is that, while there is a (known) minimum number of employees that should be assigned to each shift, it is possible to assign additional employees ("supernumeraries"), to ensure that the team assigned to the shift *collectively* has the necessary skills.
Furthermore, in our domain, there is no 1-to-1 matching between the skills of an individual employee and the skills needed during a shift; each employee has 2 to 9 skills; but through the combination of all employees on the team, we calculate a collective set of skills (which is greater that the sum of its parts), and check whether this collective set of skills is adequate for the needs of a given shift.
After reading the domain modelling guide (https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns#domainModelingGuide) I'm not sure what would be the best way to express the possibility of supernumerary employees per shift. Should I use a PlanningListVariable, or would that increase the search space unnecessarily?
Any help would be appreciated. Note: I understand that domain modelling is a skill that brings a lot of value to a business; we're trying to create some simple models in-house, in order to explore Timefold in the context of our business domain, and if it all goes well, we'll probably contact Timefold for consulting services on building the full-scale complex models.

Tried to modify Timefold's Employee Scheduling example to adapt it to my business domain.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model it as follows:

- The planning entity is Shift, with a nullable planning variable employee and fields shiftGroup, startTime, and endTime
- ShiftGroup is a problem fact with fields shifts, minimumEmployeeCount and requiredSkills
- Employee is a problem fact with fields id and skills

Do not use `@PlanningListVariable`, it has the addition restriction that each planning value will be used **exactly** once, which is useful for domains like vehicle routing, but undesired for employee scheduling.

Assuming all shifts has a ShiftGroup, the constraint provider would look like this

```java
Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[] {
        allRequiredSkills(constraintFactory),
        shiftGroupHasMinimumEmployees(constraintFactory)
        // other constraints
    };
}

Constraint allRequiredSkills(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(Shift.class)
        .groupBy(Shift::getShiftGroup)
        .expand(shiftGroup -> shiftGroup.getMissingSkillCount())
        .filter((shiftGroup, missingSkillCount) -> missingSkillCount != 0)
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (shiftGroup, missingSkillCount) -> missingSkillCount)
        .asConstraint("Missing required skill in shift");
}

Constraint shiftGroupHasMinimumEmployees(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(Shift.class)
        .groupBy(Shift::getShiftGroup)
        .expand(shiftGroup -> shiftGroup.getAssignedEmployeeCount())
        .filter((shiftGroup, employeeCount) -> employeeCount < shiftGroup.getMinimumEmployeeCount())
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (shiftGroup, employeeCount) -> shiftGroup.getMinimumEmployeeCount() - employeeCount)
        .asConstraint("Less than minimum employees in shift group");
}
```

`getMissingSkillCount()` and `getAssignedEmployeeCount()` are methods in ShiftGroup and would look like this:

```java
int getMissingSkillCount() {
    Set<String> missingSkills = new HashSet<>(requiredSkills);
    for (Shift shift : shifts) {
        if (shift.getEmployee() != null) {
            missingSkills.removeAll(shift.getEmployee().getSkills());
            if (missingSkills.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return missingSkills.size();
}

int getAssignedEmployeeCount() {
    int assignedEmployees = 0;
    for (Shift shift : shifts) {
        if (shift.getEmployee() != null) {
            assignedEmployees++;
        }
    }
    return assignedEmployees;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher for your answer! I've implemented it, but now I'm running into problems because ShiftGroup is a problem fact but contains an ArrayList of problem entities (List<Shift>), and these are not updated properly. The solver changes the employee variable in the Shift (as I can see from the solution's @-PlanningEntityCollectionProperty List<Shift> with all shifts) but this change is not propagated to the List<Shift> in ShiftGroup (despite both lists referencing the same Shift objects). I've tried annotating ShiftGroup with @-DeepPlanningClone but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: When I tried it locally by modifying the employee scheduling quickstart, I could not reproduced the behaviour with a correctly implemented solution, although at first I incorrectly implemented it and saw the same result (namely, I set the ShiftGroup for each Shift, but forgot to add each Shift to the ShiftGroup). Did you add each Shift to the ShiftGroup?